# How to get all nodes having text using XPath in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xquery

So I am pretty new to Xpath expressions and using it with Java. I am trying to parse an XML file to get all nodes having some text between the tags. For example, if I have XML as

```
<employee>
   <emp>John <age>25</age>
   </emp>
   <salary> 1000
   </salary>
</employee>
```

Then I should get

> John 25 1000

i.e., only the text content between any tags without getting duplicates.
 I am following this [tutorial](https://howtodoinjava.com/xml/java-xpath-tutorial-example/) here to use Xpath expression to get the desired values. 
I have written the following snippet:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;;

public class xpathTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("TestXmlFile.xml");

    //Create XPath

    XPathFactory xpathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xpathfactory.newXPath();

    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//*[text()]"); // to get all all nodes having some text

    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());

    }
}
```

The problem I am facing with this code is it only returning me *null* values instead of those text values. Can you please spot what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: If you want all text content of `employee` node, try `string(normalize-space(//employee))`

Comment: In the W3C DOM API you use the node value of element nodes is defined as the `null` value so no suprise there. You can use `getTextContent()` instead of `getNodeValue()`.

Comment: @Andersson exactly where do I add this line. Sorry, I am pretty new to this concept.

Comment: Martin was pretty clear:  **replace** getNodeValue() with getTextContent().

Comment: @MartinHonnen getNodeValue() does work but it is showing the values multiple times

Comment: Your document has mixed contents (i.e. the `emp` element has both text and an element child (`age` element)), furthermore the root element also is selected by the XPath you have used. So you will need to explain in more detail how you want to collect that result you have shown (or follow that initial suggestion in the first comment to output the string of a complete `employee` element).

Comment: @MartinHonnen as suggested I have added a little more detail on the kind of output I am expecting. As for the first comment, I am really not sure where to add that line.

Comment: Do you want that text `John 25 1000` as a single string? Is there more than one `employee` element?  The XPath from the first comment (i.e. `xpath.compile("string(normalize-space(//employee))")`) would give you (on the Java side) a `String` holding that value `John 25 1000` of the first `employee` element in the document. You would use the `evaluate` overload with single argument https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathExpression.html#evaluate-java.lang.Object-https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathExpression.html#evaluate-java.lang.Object-.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks. 
Yes, I want it as a single string. The employee is just a root element. So, it will occur only once. However, <emp> can occur multiple times inside <employee>

Comment: @MartinHonnen Is there anything else that I need to change in the code as I am getting this error:
Can not convert #STRING to a NodeList!

Comment: Well, yes, if you use a method that returns a `String` you need to use it as a String and not as a `NodeList`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I tried doing that and it shows error